# 403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent' error in flask

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es

I am trying to use Dialogflow in my Flask app but I am getting `403 IAM permission 'dialogflow.sessions.detectIntent'` I have checked twice my role is project owner in cloud console. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5EMHIQiGWE) tutorial.

This is my app.py

```html
from flask import Flask
from flask import request, jsonify
import os
import dialogflow
from google.api_core.exceptions import InvalidArgument
import requests

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'service_key.json'

DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'whatsappbotagent-gmsl'
DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
SESSION_ID = 'me'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Hello World"

@app.route('/api/getMessage', methods = ['POST'])
def home():
    message = request.form.get('Body')
    mobnu = request.form.get('From')
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
    session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text = message, language_code = DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text = text_input)
    try:
        response = session_client.detect_intent(session = session, query_input = query_input)
    except InvalidArgument:
        raise

    print("Query text: ", response.query_result.query_text)
    # sendMessage()
    return response.query_result.fullfilment_text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Try to import **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** as a JSON file into the code instead of using environmental variables (using environ is a better practice and that is what you should do eventually, but can cause error if not properly set up). My guess is that is causing the error, cause I do not see any problems with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after a lot of searching and trial and error I found the issue.

Actually while creating a service account the user gets a service email and that email will have access to use the project but I was not adding that email in project permission emails. Adding that email in `IAM & Admin > IAM > +ADD` will make it work.

Maybe there was a better solution but this is what works for me and hopefully solves others problem if have similar issue like this.